# Image shows up corrupted on localhost

Tags: c++, networking, webserver, boost-asio

I'm horribly new to c++ and programming in general. I'm simply trying to read a picture using opencv and display it on web server using boost asio. This is an initial step before I do this for all frames from a video. The following is my code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(){
    try{
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 1112));

        for (;;){
            tcp::socket socket(io_service);
            acceptor.accept(socket);
            boost::system::error_code ignored_error;

            cv::Mat frame = cv::imread("x.jpg");
            vector<uchar> buff;
            vector<int> param = vector<int>(2);
            param[0]=cv::IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY;
            param[1]=95;
            imencode(".jpg",frame,buff,param);

            const char mess[] = "axaxaxaxasaaaaaaaaaaxax";

            std::string content(buff.begin(), buff.end());

            boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(content), boost::asio::transfer_all(), ignored_error);
            // boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(mess), boost::asio::transfer_all(), ignored_error);
        }
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

now sending the message works just fine but when i try to send the image via content or buff, it shows up as gibberish. I feel like it's because I'm not sending any information about the picture prior to sending the picture. But I can't figure out how to do that. 
Or maybe I'm entirely wrong. Any help/advice would be appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified the code a little:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main(){
    try{
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 1112));

        for (;;){
            tcp::socket socket(io_service);
            acceptor.accept(socket);

            cv::Mat frame = cv::imread("x.jpg");
            std::vector<uchar> buff;
            imencode(".jpg", frame, buff, std::vector<int> { cv::IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 95 });

            boost::system::error_code err;
            auto bytes_transferred = boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(buff), boost::asio::transfer_all(), err);

            std::cout << "Written: " << bytes_transferred << " (" << err.message() << ")\n";
        }
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

> *(specifically, don't use `using namespace` unneccessarily, not copying into a std::string unneccessarily, and not ignoring the error code unnecessarily)*

Compiled it with

```
g++ test.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -pthread -lope^Cv_{core,imgproc,imgcodecs} -lboost_{system,thread} -o test.exe
```

Copied a sampe jpeg as x.jpg, running it in a terminal:

```
./test.exe
```

Then using  `netcat` to read the result:

```
netcat localhost 1112 > verify.jpg
```

The server process will print the same message each time:

```
Written: 6130 (Success)
```

(6130 bytes happens to be the 95% re-encoded size of the test image I chose). The resulting image (verify.jpg) looks fine in my image viewer.

### Conclusion

I think the code is probably fine (but check with the improvements above) and you might have been testing the result incorrectly.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for simplifying the code. Bit of a learning experience for me. I downloaded netcat and ran it on the original code(because I'm unable to compile the simplified one ('cannot find -lope^Cv)) to get a verify.jpg. it looks like the original picture. But, in the browser, it's still showing as a bunch of random characters. Any idea why that's happening?

Comment: Update: was able to run the simplified code. But the problem of displaying the image in the browser still persists.

Comment: Ah you didn't say you're using a browser to connect. Your response isn't a valid HTTP response, so there's that. You might not have included code that sends that part, but really consider using Boost Beast to handle HTTP request parsing and response building.

Comment: Maybe your shell isn't bash, and you need to expand the commandline yourself: `g++ test.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -pthread -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs -lboost_system -lboost_thread -o test.exe`

Comment: Thanks. A general direction was all I needed. I'll try accomplishing my task using POCO now, after which I'll look at Beast. Cheers!

Comment: POCO seems nice (but I didn't use it since ... 12 years ago)

Comment: Can you help me out with some syntax on how to write a valid response please?

Comment: It's not about syntax. It's not about how to tell the computer what to do, but on _what_ to tell the computer to do first. In POCO, you'd need [sendBuffer](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.HTTPServerResponse.html#22382) or [sendFile](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.HTTPServerResponse.html#22379)

Comment: By the way, you're posting duplicate questions, and un-accepting answers now. It looks a bit like you're just trying to get people to work harder for you. That's not how the site is intended to work. You just start at the basics and come here for help when you're stuck. Right now, you're at the basics of "what is an HTTP response": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages

Comment: aw sorry man that wasn't my intention at all. I'm just stuck here and trying to figure out how to go further about it. Hence, i was hoping to get some more help. I'll just delete the other cuz I seem to have broken the rules.

Comment: The accepting was a mistake on my part too. Apologies. I accepted the answer before i was sure it helped me solve the problem. I'll be more mindful in the future. Thnks for your help. Any inconvenience is regretted.

Comment: My advice is to take smaller steps and ask/search the concrete questions at each step where you're stuck. For example, maybe make the thing work with JUST `netcat`. Make sure you know what an HTTP response looks like. Once you do, you will know _what_ you need to code. You might have further questions when actually trying to code that in c++ and I'll see those questions at that time :)

Comment: Hi. I've posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58447312/erroneous-implementation-of-boost-beast-sync-http-server. I took your advice and tried using Boost Beast. I would appreciate it if you took a look at it. Hope I'm not breaking any rules with this.